# Mongodb can't group properly after a chain of lookup/unwined stages

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a complex query requiring a chain of nested unwinds and grouping them in order.
here are relations between models [policy, asset, assetType, field, fieldType]

- `policy` has many `asset`
- `asset` has one `assetType`
- `asset` has many `fields`
- `field` has one `fieldType`

example object would be something like, where

```js
    {
      policy: {
        ..., // policy fields
        assets: [
          {
            ..., // asset fields
            assetType: {},
            fields: [
              {
                ..., // field fields
                fieldType: {},
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    }
```

Now I'm trying to do a pipeline to get the nested date with the same structure above
this is the far I get to

```js
    mongoose.model('policy').aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'assets',
          localField: 'assets',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'assets',
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'assettypes',
          let: {
            id: '$assets._id',
            fields: '$assets.fields',
            name: '$assets.displayName',
            atId: '$assets.assetType',
          },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  $eq: ['$_id', '$$atId'],
                },
              },
            },
            {
              $project: {
                _id: '$$id',
                assetId: '$$id',
                assetDisplayName: '$$name',
                assetFields: '$$fields',
                type: 1,
                name: 1,
              },
            },
          ],
          as: 'assets',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$assets',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$assets.fields',
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'fieldtypes',
          let: {
            ftId: '$assets.fields.fieldType',
            value: '$assets.fields.value',
            ref: '$assets._id',
          },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  $eq: ['$_id', '$$ftId'],
                },
              },
            },
            {
              $addFields: {
                value: '$$value',
                assetId: '$$ref',
              },
            },
          ],
          as: 'assets.fields',
        },
      },
    ])
```

and now I'm stuck with grouping the results to get the optimal object I described above.

Can you help, please?

UPDATE: here is [Sample data](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZNWMtXZ8GCk)

Comment: Why do you use `$unwind` It seems this query can work without unwinding... Can you provide some sample documents?

Comment: What is that aggregation currently producing?

Comment: please check this sample data @nimrodserok https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZNWMtXZ8GCk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

1. Get all the relevant `assets` from the policies and `unwind` them (I guess you only want it for few selected policies, otherwise, if you want to use all `assets`, you may as well start from their collection and in the end group them by policy)
2. Get all the wanted data from other collections. Create a `fieldtypes` array in each document
3. In order to match each item in `fields` with its `fieldtype` use `$map` with `$mergeObjects` (this is the more complicated part).
4. Group by policy

```
db.policies.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "assets",
      localField: "assets",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "assets"
  }},
  {$unwind: "$assets"},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "fields",
      localField: "assets.fields",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "assets.fields"
  }},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "assettypes",
      localField: "assets.assetType",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "assets.assetType"
  }},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "fieldtypes",
      localField: "assets.fields.fieldType",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "assets.fieldtypes"
  }},
  {$set: {
      "assets.assetType": {$first: "$assets.assetType"},
      "assets.fields": {
        $map: {
          input: "$assets.fields",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {fieldType: {
                  $getField: {
                    input: {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                        "$assets.fieldtypes",
                        {$indexOfArray: ["$assets.fieldtypes._id", "$$this.fieldType"]}
                      ]
                    },
                    field: "key"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "assets.fieldtypes": "$$REMOVE"
    }
  },
  {$group: {_id: "$_id", assets: {$push: "$assets"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZibDEVQEH1m)